# Small handlers at end and beginning

Tags: circuits

I want to draw several diagrams for boolean circuits, as `$w + x(y + zx')$`. Is there a Tikz's library to draw this component?

[image: basic element of a circuit]

I'm sure there is a right way to do it but can't find anything in circuits library. I have this so far:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw (1.07,-0.014) node {$\circ$};
    \draw (1.5,0.07) node {$x$};
    \draw (2-0.07,-0.014) node {$\circ$};
    \draw (2,0) -- (3,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

EDIT: Jul 10, 2019, 07:27 CDT

Just found `arrows.meta` library and the tip `Circle[open]`, so I improved my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) [arrows = -{Circle[open]}] -- (1,0);    
\draw (1.25,0.07) node {$x$}; 
\draw (1.5,0) [arrows = {Circle[open]}-] -- (2.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Looks fine to me!

[image: Arrow with Circle[open] tip]

Comment: Do you have a web link that explains this notation `$w + x(y + zx')$`?

Comment: @AndréC, they are boolean variables, + is unión, product is intersection, and prima is complement. Shannon use dual meaning in http://www.ccapitalia.net/descarga/docs/1938-shannon-analysis-relay-switching-circuits.pdf

Comment: Is your last update an answer to your problem?

Comment: Yes @AndréC, it is!

Comment: It is better to answer your own question by stating that my solution gave you the idea. Answering your own question is encouraged here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Sorry @AndréC, but I didn't get the idea from your proposal!!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a library that does what you want. And I'm not sure I'll answer your question.

I created an `arrow` with TikZ that I called `circ` which has a `radius of 1.5pt`.

```
\pgfdeclarearrow{ 
    name = circ,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{3\arrowsize}{0}} {3\arrowsize}%
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}
```

The arrow is the same size as `\circ`. And I anchored the text to the base so it would be the same height as yours.

[image: screenshot]

```
   \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \pgfdeclarearrow{ 
    name = circ,
parameters = { },
setup code = { },
drawing code = {
    \newdimen\arrowsize%
    \arrowsize=0.5pt%
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}%
    \pgfsetmiterjoin%
    \advance\arrowsize by .25\pgflinewidth
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{3\arrowsize}{0}} {3\arrowsize}%
    \pgfusepathqfillstroke%
    },
defaults = { }
}
    \begin{document}
    % We see that the new arrow circ at the same size as `\circ`
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[-circ] (0,0) -- (1,0);% new arrow circ
    \draw (1.5,0.07) node {$x$};
    \draw (2-0.07,0) node {$\circ$};% \circ
    \draw (2,0) -- (3,0);

    \begin{scope}[blue,yshift=-5mm]
     % second draw with new circ arrow only
    \draw[-circ] (0,0) -- (1,0)node (a){};
    \draw[circ-] (2,0)node(b){} -- (3,0);
    \node[anchor=base] at ($(a)!.5!(b)$) {$x$};
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun, a veryshort code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} 

\begin{document}

\begin{psmatrix}[mnode=r, emnode=p, colsep=0.8cm]
[name = L] & \psDefBoxNodes{X}{\makebox[2em]{$x$}} & [name=R]
\psset{ arrows =o-, linewidth=0.4pt,}%
\psline(X:Cl)(L) \psline(X:Cr)(R)%
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image]